# Using Map with mget yields unexpected output

Tags: r, mapply

I have a number of lists :say list1, list2,....and list 100 and function `myfun` . With these, I can run `Map(myfun,list1,list2,...,list100)`. However, I want to avoid writing all list numbers, and so I tried `Map(myfun,mget(paste0("list",1:100)))`. But, this didn't work. A reproducible example with only three lists is provided below:

```
x1<-list(1:10,10:20)
x2<-list(0:9,11:20)
x3<-list(100:109,41:50)

Map(rbind,x1,x2,x3) #ok
mget(paste0("x",1:3)) #ok
Map(rbind,mget(paste0("x",1:3))) #ok but the unexpected output

Map(rbind,mget(paste0("x",1:3)))
$x1
     [,1]       [,2]      
[1,] Integer,10 Integer,10

$x2
     [,1]       [,2]      
[1,] Integer,10 Integer,10

$x3
     [,1]       [,2]      
[1,] Integer,10 Integer,10
```

Comment: `mget` returns a list of lists, compared to just using `x1` etc. which are single list objects.

Comment: You are correct. Any alternatives to include the list numbers?

Comment: Probably something like `Reduce(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), mget(paste0("x",1:3)))`

Comment: Perfect. Please post that as an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mget` returns a list of list (see `?mget` under *"Value"*), as opposed to parsing each list as a separate vector into `Map`. A possible way to deal with it, is to `Reduce` the list back to its original elements and then `rbind` them, something like

```
Reduce(function(...) Map(rbind, ...), mget(paste0("x", 1:3)))
```

Comment: NP, though there could be possibly a more efficient solution